# How is this equation solved? Quadratic formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Equation:

$25x^2 - 150x = 472$

According to http://www.homeschoolmath.net/worksheets/equation_calculator.php, it has two solutions:

$x = \frac{\sqrt{697}-15}{5}$

$x = -2.28015$

And

$x = \frac{\sqrt{697}+15}{5}$

$x = 8.28015$

But, how do I get there?

---

Thanks for your help! So I use the cuadratic formula:

$ x = \frac{-(-150) + \sqrt{(-150)^2 - 4(25)(-472)}}{2(25)} $

$ x = \frac{150 + \sqrt{22500 + 47200}}{50} $

$ x = \frac{150 + 264}{50} $

$ x = 8.28 $

And if I use the minus, I get:

$ x = -2.28 $

The answers are the same ones as in the calculator I posted.

This is the first time I use a cuadratic formula. It's amazing, haha. Thanks for your help.

@MatMorPau22 got something like this:

$ x_1=\frac{15+\sqrt{697}}{5} $

It returns the same value ($ 8.28 $), but how did he get that?

Maybe some step by step could help. Thanks a lot for your time and help!!

Comment: Quadratic equation you can look it up

Comment: [Quadratic Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula_and_its_derivation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [quadratic equation](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwif6djKtNfUAhVCyoMKHbWDC4sQFghcMAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FQuadratic_equation&usg=AFQjCNEEZ-QYloaEoSMYKrv8Xh82ROIdEg), and can be written in the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$. You can solve these equations by using the [quadratic formula](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjfnenKtNfUAhWm3YMKHQmPBPAQFgguMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FQuadratic_formula&usg=AFQjCNH8gboySF3Ja2wT0B-w4wq_60BGww),
$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
Note that the $\pm$ accounts for both solutions (i.e. one solution will use the plus and the other will use the minus).

In your case we can write the equation as $25x^2-150x-472=0$, where we can then use $a=25,b=-150,c=-472$ in the above formula.

**Addressing your second question:** to see why $\frac{15+\sqrt{697}}{5}$ is a solution, we have:
$$\begin{align}x_1&=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\qquad a=25,b=-150,c=-472\\&=\frac{150+\sqrt{22500-4(25)(-472)}}{2(25)}\\&=\frac{150+\sqrt{69700}}{50}\\&=\frac{150+\sqrt{100}\sqrt{697}}{50}\\&=\frac{10(15+\sqrt{697})}{10(5)}\qquad \text{since $\sqrt{100}=10$}\\&=\frac{15+\sqrt{697}}{5}\end{align}$$

Comment: thanks for you answer and the links! I'll check them out, please see my edit.

Comment: @JoseCarlosRamírez I just added a detailed procedure for seeing that $\frac{15+\sqrt{697}}{5}$ is a solution.

Answer (score 4):

In second degreee equation like $ax^2+bx+c=0$, you can apply $x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$. In your case, $a=25$, $b=-150$ and $c=-472$. So, put in the formula and work it a little bit and you get
$x_1=\frac{15+\sqrt{697}}{5}$ and $x_2=\frac{15-\sqrt{697}}{5}$.

Check it again, your initial solution is wrong

Comment: how do you get 15 in the numerator and 5 in the denominator? Thanks foru your time! please see my edit.

Comment: It's just simplifiying the result, the discriminant ($\Delta=b^2-4ac$) equals $b^2-4ac=150*150-4*25*(-472)=69700$, so $\sqrt{69700}=\sqrt{697}\sqrt{100}=10\sqrt{697}$ and then you have $x=\frac{150\pm10\sqrt{697}}{50}=\frac{15\pm\sqrt{697}}{5}$

Comment: thas was great, thanks a lot! I will mark the other one cause it has a step by step very illustrative to other users, but thanks, your answer helped a lot too!!